# Experimental Verification of Quantum Field Theory vs Classical Field Theory

Tags: quantum-field-theory, classical-mechanics, classical-field-theory

I have heard one statement that appears, in varied form, throughout many Quantum Field Theory (QFT) books and lectures:

> QFT is the most accurate framework in all of Physics.

and then the result such as muon $g-2$ is mentioned which is accurate up-to many significant digits. I want to know what is/are the other classical result(s) that are being comparing with so as to deem QFT to be most accurate. Are not there any classical Field Theory (or classical physics as a whole) results (may be unrelated to muon $g-2$), say from the Classical Electromagnetism where the results match with theory **more** accurately?

Comment: I mean, if you are comparing to classical field theory then there are results going back to the earliest day of quantum theory, such as the photoelectric effect, where the classical theory is *qualitatively wrong*

Comment: The stability of the hydrogen atom.

Comment: I've heard it said that the general relativity (GR) predictions of decaying binary pulsars match our observations to comparable or better accuracy than g-2, but after a quick search I'm not so sure.  It seems that you can measure the period of these pulsars to 10-12 significant figures, but that's not the same as a claim that the GR predictions match observations to 10-12 significant figures.  The predictions give decay rates, not absolute frequencies.

Comment: General Relativity is 100% classical and has passed all experimental tests so far. It's not particle physics, so it's a different domain, but good to know that it has been the other pillar of modern physics (along with quantum mechanics) for the past >100 years.

Comment: I wonder, what exactly does "classical" mean? Classical field theory using the quantum effective action reproduces quantum effects "classically"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No; the classical theory started failing over a century ago, and quantum mechanics replaced it conclusively a century ago. Nobody has ever matched the 14 decimal points of the [electron g-factor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G-factor_(physics)#Measured_g-factor_values) in the Lamb shift classically.

That is, classical theories might strain to compute -2, whilst the  [latest experimental result](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevLett.130.071801), -2.002 319 304 361 18(27) agrees with the QFT theoretical calculation to 1 part in $10^{12}$.

Looks like an unequal contest...

"Discrepancies" between theory and experiment you might hear about these days in the clueless science reporting on the muon g-factor refer to structural uncertainties of computational techniques, technicalities; not fundamental possibilities of barking up the wrong tree.